# I need a bash script that replaces every number between two arrows in a file with a 0

Tags: xml

the name of the file is types.xml and lists hundreds of different items.

this is what it looks like:

```
    <type name="CanisterGasoline">
        <nominal>50</nominal>
        <lifetime>28800</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>30</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="tools"/>
        <tag name="shelves"/>
        <usage name="Industrial"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Canteen">
        <nominal>20</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>0</restock>
        <min>10</min>
        <quantmin>10</quantmin>
        <quantmax>90</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="food"/>
        <usage name="Military"/>
    </type>
```

basically, everywhere it says `<nominal>20</nominal>` , I want to change whatever the number is between `<nominal>` and `</nominal>` to 0.

thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with `sed` you can do it like this:

```
sed 's@<nominal>[0-9]*</nominal>@<nominal>0</nominal>@' types.xml > output.xml
```

That replaces `<nominal>` followed by any sequence of digits followed by `</nominal>` with `<nominal>0</nominal>`.

But I'm sure someone will be along very soon to suggest why you should use a dedicated XML parser to do this, and suggest which one and how.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the XML document is well-formed (your example is lacking a root node), you may use `xmlstarlet` to replace the values of any `nominal`-node with zero, if the node's value is 20, like so:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -u '//nominal[text() = 20]' -v 0  types.xml
```

This edits (`ed`) the data by updating (`-u`) all `nominal` nodes anywhere in the input document (`//nominal`) whose value is 20 (`[text() = 20]`), setting the value of the node to zero (`-v 0`).

Adding a root node to your example document and running this results in

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <type name="CanisterGasoline">
    <nominal>50</nominal>
    <lifetime>28800</lifetime>
    <restock>0</restock>
    <min>30</min>
    <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
    <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
    <cost>100</cost>
    <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
    <category name="tools"/>
    <tag name="shelves"/>
    <usage name="Industrial"/>
  </type>
  <type name="Canteen">
    <nominal>0</nominal>
    <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
    <restock>0</restock>
    <min>10</min>
    <quantmin>10</quantmin>
    <quantmax>90</quantmax>
    <cost>100</cost>
    <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
    <category name="food"/>
    <usage name="Military"/>
  </type>
</root>
```

With `xmlstarlet` you can even update the value with some other value from the document, for example the parent node's `restock` value:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -u '//nominal[text() = 20]' -x '../restock/text()'  types.xml
```

The `xmlstarlet` utility can do in-place edits if you give it the `-L` or `--inplace` option right after `ed` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Or use `regex`'s "back references" like

```
sed 's@\(<nominal>\)[0-9]*\(</nominal>\)@\10\2@' types.xml
```